# Не могу провести миграцию БД EF при наличии 2-х проектов в решение

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api, миграция, c#-8.0

Есть 2 проекта в одно Решение: Библиотека Классов и Web API

[image: Файловая Структура]

DBLib\LibContext.cs

```
using DBLib.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DBLib
{
    public class LibContext : DbContext
    {
        public LibContext(DbContextOptions<LibContext> option) : base(option) { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Author)
                .WithMany(u => u.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
        }
    }
}
```

EDU_API\Program.cs

```
using DBLib;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<LibContext>(option =>
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Вывод в Консоль диспетчера пакетов:

[image: Консоль Диспетчера Пакетов]

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[DBLib.LibContext]' while attempting to activate 'DBLib.LibContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728